# MySQL Error Code

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to insert a data into mysql however, I am receiving an error code which says "Column Count doesn't match value count at row 1" May I know whats the issue with my code below? Thank you.

```
insert into Student(Studentno,studentFName,StudentLName,DateOfBirth,YearEnrolled,YearGraduated)
Values
(123,'JungKook','Jeon','M','1September1997',2015,2018);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're supplying more values in the `VALUES` part of your query than fields in the `INSERT INTO Student` part.

It looks like 'M' is a value the field for which you have not included a field name between `StudentLName` and `DateOfBirth`.

Answer (score 0):

You have more values a s column names in your SQL. You have a value fr gender in the list of values, but no column.

```
insert into Student(Studentno,studentFName,StudentLName,Gender, DateOfBirth,YearEnrolled,YearGraduated) Values (123,'JungKook','Jeon','M','1September1997',2015,2018);
```